# How to write certain children of root XML successively into new file, Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm starting with a big XML file, and trying to create a new file with only the elements that I want (one's containing a certain serial number). I have almost everything working, the only problem is that when I go to write the elements into a new file, it seems to be writing over itself over and over and I end up with only the last element printed in the file. How can I make it so that when the next element writes to the file it will start after the previous one? I'm thinking some type of line count and insert I just don't know how to format that.

Here is my loop that finds the elements I want and writes them to the file:

```
for child in root:
    for element in child:
        if element.tag == 'DeviceId':
            if element.text == 'NS-00-00000':
                f = open('new_3.log','w')
                p = (ET.tostringlist(child, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
                print(p)
                f.write('\n'.join(p))
                f.close()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Open the file _before_ the loop starts, and close it after the loop finishes.

Comment: as in all the way outside to top for statement? Should I close it in the loop or take that out to? Thanks

Comment: Yes, before the outermost `for` loop.  And close it after that loop is finished.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Could you explain why that fixes it?

Comment: Opening a file in `'w'` mode destroys the existing contents.  So you only want to do that once.

Comment: Thank you very much